# saving the file in the specified location using libcurl

Tags: libcurl

I want to download a file from a URL using libcurl in C. I want to save the downloaded file into a specified location (i.e., /mnt/jffs2/ ) in my POS device.

I got code from some one and failed on executing that. Rather I can't save that file in my desired location.

So anyone help me please.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Most easily you use the default [CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html#CURLOPTWRITEFUNCTION) (which calls fwrite) and just set [CURLOPT_WRITEDATA](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html#CURLOPTWRITEDATA) to the FILE * of your target file:

```
FILE *body = fopen("/mnt/jffs2/storeit", "w");
...
curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, body);'
...
rc = curl_easy_perform(curl_handle);
```